# dynamically add annotation to a generated groovy method

Tags: groovy, annotations

I want to generate the test methods in groovy (based on a data set). I use JUnit and I want to add a `@Test` annotation to each method generated by myself.

So far I have this code:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void addAutoDetectPluginsTest() {
    AutoDetectPluginsTest.metaClass."test plugin-01" = { -> println("plugin-01")}
}
```

What is the way to add an annotation `@Test` to the method `test plugin-01` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your approach with the meta class cannot work. What ever you do in Groovy's meta class system, it does not affect reflection. And JUnit will look for those annotations using reflection. Thus it cannot work. You would probably have to rewrite the bytecode for the class on loading... for example using an agent. But I don't think you want to go that far.